# NoSuchMethodError in JNI to Java Exception

Tags: java, android, exception, java-native-interface, nosuchmethoderror

I am getting this error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/lang/AssertionError;.(Ljava/lang/String;)V"

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass( "java/lang/AssertionError" );

env->ThrowNew( clazz, "Test Assertion" );
```

Note: env is JNIEnv*

Any thoughts? I see that AssertionError exists. I am seeing this on Android Lollipop only. It seems to be fine on android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.AssertionError` [doesn't have the constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) mentioned in the error message. So you can't use `ThrowNew(),` which relies on that.

You'll have to construct the exception yourself and use `Throw().`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass( "java/lang/AssertionError" );

env->ThrowNew( clazz, "Test Assertion" );
```

I don't know where exceptionClass comes from, but you didn't set it here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was a typo on my side while trying to make a snippet for the question. However, the original problem still exists.